# how to generate repeatable Unique streams?

Tags: programming, code-review

I need to label some data in arbitrarily nested ragged lists, with a stream of unique labels. It's very convenient if the labels are consecutive integers, starting at `0` or `1`, and if I can produce the same stream every time I label a given data set.

I can do this with recursive functions that thread around the current label in the parameter list and conventionally in every output (say the first element in a list, by convention; this is essentially an explicit simulation of the state monad of Haskell). It's cumbersome and ugly, so I'm looking for a better solution.

`Unique` comes close to fitting the bill. In a fresh kernel, MMA version 9.0.1 on Mac 10.8.4, consider the following

```
Table[Unique[],{3}] 

{$3, $4, $5}
```

Great. Let's try starting them at 1, following the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ModuleNumber.html?q=$ModuleNumber&lang=en),

```
$ModuleNumber = 1; 
Table[Unique[], {3}]

{$6, $7, $8}
```

Ooops, surprise!

The following, which was my first attempt, produces an internal ENULL bugcheck

```
Block[{$ModuleNumber = 1},
 Table[Unique[], {3}]]
```

> Mathematica has detected an internal error:
>         vMessage ENULL
>
> Please report this error as soon as possible to
>       support@wolfram.com giving as many details as possible
>       of the circumstances under which it occurred.

I can mimic the entire thing with my own global state variable and mimic of `Unique`, but thought I'd first check here for insight and advice.

Comment: I wouldn't play with `$ModuleNumber` in any case. Who knows what that may break. At the very least, you can break the uniqueness of variables produced by `Module`, and that can lead to all sort of bugs.

Comment: I understand the warning (and basically agree with it, outside of toys, and I was making a toy). It is interesting that the documentation explicitly states that `$ModuleNumber` can be reset, even outside a `Block`. But then, it doesn't actually work :)

Comment: Perhaps, redefining `$ModuleNumber` may have some constructuve uses which I am unaware of. But personally I would not mess with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use this solution:

```
newStream[start_: 1] := Module[{i = start}, i++ &]

s = newStream[];
Table[s[], {5}]
(* Out: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)

s = newStream[20];
Table[s[], {5}]
(* Out: {20, 21, 22, 23, 24} *)
```

This avoids having a global variable, and you can have many streams at the same time.

Comment: Seems like closure.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something along those lines?

```
nextlabel[] := StringTemplate["`` label"][++lastlabel]



lastlabel = 0;
Table[ nextlabel[], {10} ]
```

> ```
> {"1 label", "2 label", "3 label", "4 label", "5 label", "6 label", 
> "7 label", "8 label", "9 label", "10 label"}
> ```