# Unique[] problems

Tags: symbols

A fresh *Mathematica* session with

```
$Version
"11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)"
```

produces the following results.

```
Names["x*"]
(* {} *)
Table[Unique["x"], 4]
(* {x3, x4, x5, x6} *)
Names["x*"]
(* {"x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"} *)
```

The first thing one notices is that, according to the *Mathematica* documentation, the results of `Unique` should be

```
(* {x1, x2, x3, x4} *)
```

In fact, even executing (in a fresh session) the first basic example in the `Unique` documentation changes `Out[1]` from `x1` to `x3`.  To continue,

```
Remove["x*"]
Names["x*"]
(* {} *)
```

apparently removes all traces of the `x` symbols, but it does not reset the `Unique` counter

```
Table[Unique["x"], 4]
(* {x7, x8, x9, x10} *)
```

The counter even persists across different families of symbols.

```
Table[Unique["z"], 4]
(* {z11, z12, z13, z14} *)
```

It also persists across contexts, but not across kernels.

How can this `Unique` counter (which is not `$ModuleNumber`) be reset?  And, is this a bug?

Comment: According to the docs, `Unique` is using the same `$ModuleNumber` counter as `Module`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin not for strings.

Comment: I get the same behavior going back to version 9

Comment: @Feyre Indeed, my bad.

Comment: Documentation doesn't promise that you will have full control over this counter or that internal procedures won't use `Unique["string"]`. If you want something you can rely on, try this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103751/5478

Comment: @Kuba  Thanks for the custom function to generate unique sequential symbols.  Nonetheless, I believe that either `Unique` or its documentation has a problem, which should be fixed.

Comment: @Kuba nonetheless it claims that "`Unique["x"]` uses the first unused symbol of the form `xnnn`". One would assume the "first" one in a new kernel is the one where `nnn` is the first positive integer.

Comment: @Feyre I don't know, then you could agrue that `$ModuleNumber` should be `1` for a fresh kernel too. Both cases probably start with `1` but are used in autoloaded packages or something, why not really. Maybe built in packages should not interfere but there are more problems with documentation that are higher on my concerns' list :)

Comment: in a related manner is evaluating the symbol `$ModuleNumber` supposed to change its value?  It does in strange ways and I see nothing in the docs to say it should.

Comment: Same behavior on 8.0.4 Mac OS X 10.11