# How to build a function which remembers function results

Tags: function-construction

I want to define a function `fun`, a function `funResult` such and a function `HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning` such that

```
In[1]:= fun[]
Out[1]= result1

In[2]:= fun[]
Out[2]= result2

In[3]:= fun[]
Out[3]= result3

In[4]:= funResult
Out[4]= {result1,result2,result3}

In[5]:= HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning 
Out[5]= 3
```

Comment: I think this should answer your question: [how to generate repeatable Unique streams?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27691/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Good link.I will edit my question to show the difference with that question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on linked topic

```
Module[{i = 0}
  , funResult := fun /@ Range@HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning
  ; HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning := i
  ; fun[] := fun[i] = (++i)^4
];
```

I'm not appeding to `funResult` but memoize those results in `fun` to make it faster when `fun` is called repeatedly.

```
Table[fun[], 5]
fun[]
```

> ```
> {1, 16, 81, 256, 625}
>
> 1296
> ```

```
HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
funResult
```

> ```
> {1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296}
> ```

Comment: Still confused,because your `fun` is based on `HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning` totally.But if my `fun` is `fun[n_]:=N[Tanh[n]]`.How to make it have that memory function?

Comment: There is no `fun[asd_]` request in your question. Make sure to include all needed features.

Comment: I should add the feature I need or post another question?Sometimes,the implement-method will change the topic a little.I realized that question after I read your answer.I'm feel sorry for that..

Comment: @yode At this point it is probably better to ask another one. But make sure you have thought everything through before you post.

Answer (score 2):

I would assign `UpValues` to the symbol `fun`. See the documentation for `TagSet` and `UpSet`, which are interchangeable here:

```
(* Initialize, UpSet syntax *) 
In[1]:= HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning[fun] ^= 0;
funResult[fun] ^= {};

(* Function definition, TagSet syntax *)
In[3]:= fun[] := (
  fun /: HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning[fun] = 
   HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning[fun] + 1;
  fun /: funResult[fun] = Append[funResult[fun], result1]
  )

In[4]:= fun[]
Out[4]= {result1}

In[5]:= fun[]
Out[5]= {result1, result1}

In[6]:= fun[]
Out[6]= {result1, result1, result1}

In[9]:= HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning[fun]
Out[9]= 3

In[10]:= funResult[fun]
Out[10]= {result1, result1, result1}
```

By using UpValues, all values are assigned to the symbol `fun` instead of `HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning` and `funResult`, which remain undefined:

```
In[11]:= Definition[fun]
Out[11]=
funResult[fun]^={result1,result1,result1}
HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning[fun]^=3
fun[]:=(fun/:HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning[fun] = HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning[fun]+1;
fun/:funResult[fun]=Append[funResult[fun],result1])

In[16]:= Defintion[HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning]
Out[16]= Defintion[HowManyTimesHasBeenRunning]
```

Note that I just wrote `result1` every time. You may of course replace that with some actual code.

Comment: Inspiring!Having you see my [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139009/21532)?

Comment: Same idea obviously. But why did you repost the question and not refine this one?

Comment: Kuba [suggest](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138998/how-to-build-a-function-which-remembers-function-results#comment375398_139000) that it will be mess.Anyway,thanks all the same. :)