# How to achieve with Mathematica the effect a closure has in other languages?

Tags: function-construction, core-language, algorithm

### Motivation

I want to write an auxiliary function (brief `auxf`) for testing the output of another function that evaluates its body repeatedly using `Pause` in between evaluations.

This auxiliary function ideally must return a different value each time it is evaluated; those values need not be sequential but it's helpful if they are monotonic and deterministic.

The idea is to have a sense of what the output *should* be and juxtaposed it to the actual output of the function being tested in order to discern what branches get executed repeatedly etc.

### Proposed approach

Now, what I could come up with was an `auxf` inspired by what I think *generators* are supposed to do in *Python* or what the *iota* operator does for *Go* constants.

Briefly, I figured that a function that increases its output value by a certain delta for every successive evaluation would be ideal for this type of situation.

After doing some (*soul*) searching I managed to combine [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) amazing post with [that](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html) piece of info from the documentation (first example in the *Applications* section) to obtain `counter` (please note that `auxf` above and `faux` below are not related):

```
Module[{i = 0, reset, faux, invldoptval},
  reset[] := (i = 0;);
  counter::invldoptval = "Invalid option value '`1`'. Expected boolean.";
  Options[counter] = {"Reset" -> False};
  counter[args___] := faux[args];
  faux[args___, OptionsPattern[counter]] := Module[{resetQ = OptionValue["Reset"]},
     If[resetQ, reset[], i++, Message[counter::invldoptval, resetQ]]
   ]
 ]
```

### Example

An example:

```
counter/@Range[5]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

Resetting the `counter`:

```
counter["Reset"->True]
counter[]
counter[]
```

> ```
> 0
> 1
> ```

Evaluating `counter` with a wrong option value like in

```
 counter["Reset"->None]
 counter[]
```

produces a message

> ```
> Invalid option value 'None'. Expected boolean.  
> 2
> ```

### Question

- Is there another idiomatic way to achieve a similar result as `counter`?

  - Are there any problems with this approach?
  - Can you think of other use cases for this piece of code?

Thanks!

Comment: How closely is this related: [How to generate repeatable Unique streams?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27691/5478)? Also, I'm not sure I understand how is the title related to questions at the bottom.

Comment: I think the accepted answer to your link is an implementation of the link in the question (the former dates from '16 while the later dates from'12); as far as I can tell it is a simpler version of what `counter` does; the question is "is there better way to achieve the same effect that `counter` delivers?" (perhaps I should've incorporated 2 and 3 in 1); as far as the title is concerned would you be so kind as to explain on what level you experience the disconnect? I wasn't aware closures were possible in MA and what `counter` does is it "[...]create[s] closure" ([link](https://goo.gl/wHFLM5))

Comment: I wrote a brief tutorial on using closures in Mathematica way back in 2011 in a personal blog. I find that basically no one uses them like this and very few people are even aware that Module preserves its private values in this way - even among pretty advanced users. I never thought to use Option in this way. That's really neat. I generally don't find it really useful to do this kind of stuff though. The internal state hurts referential transparency and is a bit heavy for lighter scripting. I've only really used this before in creating a logging tool that I only use for myself.

Comment: I understand the connection between counter and closure. I meant the whole title which is a question by itself and imo it is much broader to the question's content. I may be confused though. P.s. for other use of closures lookup Villegas-Gayley.

Comment: @Kuba I'm by all means open to suggestions about the title and/or the q itself; the Villegas-Gayley trick seems really useful esp. for logging/testing purposes which I'm currently interested in; I'm struggling to see how it relates to `counter` though; hopefully after I digest UnevaluatedExpressions.nb I'll figure it out; thanks for the pointer it is really appreciated

Comment: @Searke I wasn't aware either before reading the post in the link in the Q (I'm definitely not an advanced user); I understand your point about transparency but I'm not sure how to quantify 'weight' in this case although I'm really disappointed that `counter` seems to need a lot of work before it starts acting like how I intended it to; I wouldn't mind reading your tutorial on closures if it's still available