# How to create a notebook dialog that can receive contents dynamically?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, interactive

When coding in notebook, I'm trying to show result(s) in a `Single Notbook Dialog` by this,

```
fPreview[content_,opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
    CreateDialog[
    Pane[content, 
        ImageSize -> {500-10, 600-20},
        Scrollbars -> True, 
        AppearanceElements -> None, 
        Alignment -> Center],
        WindowTitle -> "Preview" <> " " <> ToString@Head@content,
        WindowSize -> {500, 600},opts]
```

i.e.

```
 fPreview@Plot[Sin[x],{x,-4,4}]
 fPreview@Plot3D[Sin[x y],{x,-4,4},{x,-4,4}]
```

but once `fPreview` applied, there be a new `Notebook Dialog`, so I wonder how to modify the upper codes so that there be only `One Notebook Dialog` instance displaying the latest content(s)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many additional features one could need here but let's address exactly what you have asked for:

```
  (* I will skip styling options for clarity*)

fPreview[content_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := With[
  { nb = CreateDialog[ content, opts] }
, ClearAll[fPreview]
; fPreview[new_, nvm___] := NotebookWrite[
    First @ Cells[nb], 
    Cell @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ new
  ]
]
```

In general you may need to do something based on this pattern: [how to generate repeatable Unique streams?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27691/5478), just instead of `i++&` it should return a log function you can use to log your results. And this way you can have many notebooks at once.

Comment: Thanks!  It comes `$Failed` when `fPreview` executed a second time if the `Notebook Dialog` created at the first time was closed, I try to fix it but get failure.